# Recorded acoustic guitar with Focusrite Scarlett 6i6 and Pro Tools | First but getting noise

Tags: guitar, recording

Just bought my Focusrite Scarlett 6i6 and recorded a acoustic guitar with Pro Tools | First but I'm getting some noise kind of thing in the recording.

I'm a newbie in this field so any kind of help or suggestions will be appreciated :)

[Sample Guitar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/76acldmk9jr7cf5/Audio%201_01-01.wav?dl=0)

Comment: Important info here would include your mic setup (what type, what distance from the guitar, etc.) and an idea of gain levels on the 6i6 and ProTools

Comment: @DrMayhem Actually I have a semi-acoustic guitar so no distance just plugged in and played.

Comment: Okay - in that case I'd want to check gain levels and battery, as the slight clipping could be from the signal hitting a voltage rail that has been brought low by a low battery.

Comment: @DrMayhem ... Can this be caused by guitar wire? Its a cheap one

Comment: I guess it could be, but I've gigged for years with cheap and expensive cables and there is usually no difference except for the cheap ones falling to pieces faster.

Answer (score 1):

I use a 6i6 as well. Usually things like that come down to a few simple contact/electrical issues. I would make sure my guitar cable to the interface is a good one or try another cable. Also look at what else is plugged into or near the outlet where your 6i6 is. Do you have a light fixture, another piece of equipment, your computer. A surge protector/power conditioner might eliminate the buzz. However there are known popping/clicking sounds associated with Scarlett interfaces. Go to http://us.focusrite.com/downloads?product=Scarlett+6i6 for additional assistance or call their customer support.

Comment: I have a cheap guitar cable... Do you think that might be a problem? ... I don't hear anything when I'm connected ... When I strum then there is a minor noise.